# How can i check that the LinearLayout is clicked or not

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

This is my xml file and as you can see it is nested many times by Linear layout.

---

> What i want to acheive is when I click on the area of llOptionA(First
> Linear Layout) i will get notified by a toast.

---

I have also put a toast on llOptionA.setonclickListener()
But when i click on the text it does nothing.

then I also set onclicklisteners on each of them giving me different toasts -> svTest ,layout_inner ,tvOptionA. and also i clicked everywhere to see which part is showing which toast.

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llOptionA"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff00ff"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/svTest"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_inner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvOptionA"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="A - Option A "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** a LinearLayout does not listen for click events by default even when you set an OnClickListener.  You also need to add this attribute to your LinearLayout `llOptionA`:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

**Second** a click starts at the highest level, TextView `tvOptionA`, and works it's way down until a View consumes this event. So before it reaches `llOptionA` your HorizontalScrollView intercepts the click in it's default OnTouchListener and doesn't pass it down to your `llOptionA`... You can listener for a click event with an OnTouchListener in your HorizontalScrollView to call the appropriate method.

**Third** perhaps this is a simplified layout, but the LinearLayout `layout_inner` only has one child and therefor is not necessary, you can simply use this:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <HorizontalScrollView ...>
        <TextView .../>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Of course `llOptionA` only has one child so you could simplify it more:

```
<HorizontalScrollView ...>
    <TextView .../>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

---

**Addition from comments**

Here is how to put it all together:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llOptionA);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                toast();
            }
        });

        HorizontalScrollView hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svTest);
        hsv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    toast();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void toast() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is just a part of my code the nesting is even so i can't simplify like you told however you gave me a good info regarding clicks priority and levels. thankx for that but it didn't solve my problem. your clickable doesn't work.

Comment: @HishamMuneer I updated my second item and provided an example. Now it should work.

Comment: thanks for all your help... It made my code much more messy but finally It worked...I think return should be true...

Comment: When I return `true` the ScrollView doesn't scroll any more... You can also remove some code by using the XML attribute `android:onClick="something"` and `public void something(View v)` in your Activity.

Comment: I didn't set the onTouchLister() instead i set the onLongClickLister() on tvOptionA and I also wrap_content everything inside HorizontalScrollView...